# CSS/JS Slideshow of background images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make several background images to change over time. I have tried lots of things but nothing helped. Also I need 2 buttons for left and right, but I do not know how to connect them to the slideshow. Please help.

CSS

```
.slideSh {
height:900px;
background-image: url("images/back.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slideSh"> </div>
```

Comment: "I have tried lots of things ..." Such as ?

Comment: Just use a carousel/slideshow plugin. What kind of help are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Please provide examples and code of what you've already tried.

Comment: Do you need the images to actually slide or just change?

Comment: I need it to slide.

Comment: I scrapped the codes I used, sorry

Comment: Just try something like this - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp. Plain javascript/CSS and super simple.

Comment: I need it to be a background image

Answer (score 0):

Use the Nivo Slider:

```
<!-- Usually in the <head> section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" 
/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>


<!-- Then somewhere in the <body> section -->
<div id="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="images/slide4.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/code-your-own-juicy-tabbed-slider-using-the-nivo-slider--net-18724

Comment: I need it as a background image